# How to use ST_UNION in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis, geography

I have a table in BigQuery, called `project.dataset.table`. This table, among some other columns, has an `ourpolygons` column, with datatype `GEOGRAPHY`.

I am trying to apply `ST_UNION` to the `ourpolygons` column, to get a multipolygon, a union of all our polygons. `ST_UNION` is a [Geography function in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions).

Using [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/237648/191643), I tried:

```
SELECT ST_UNION(ourpolygons) FROM (SELECT ourpolygons FROM `project.dataset.table`) AS multipolig;
```

I get the error:

```
No matching signature for function ST_UNION for argument types: GEOGRAPHY. Supported signatures: ST_UNION(GEOGRAPHY, GEOGRAPHY); ST_UNION(ARRAY<GEOGRAPHY>) at [1:8]
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT ST_UNION(ourpolygons) FROM `project.dataset.table` AS multipolig;
```

Giving me the error:

```
No matching signature for function ST_UNION for argument types: GEOGRAPHY. Supported signatures: ST_UNION(GEOGRAPHY, GEOGRAPHY); ST_UNION(ARRAY<GEOGRAPHY>) at [1:8]
```

Eventually, I would put the result into a new table, with one row: the union.

**How do I select all polygons from an existing table and  create their union?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `ST_UNION_AGG` instead of `ST_UNION`

`ST_UNION` is to make a union *horizontally* in your table: when you have a column with an array of geography object that you want to transform into a single one, or two columns of geography objects that you want to merge into two.
At the end of the operation, your table has the same number of rows.

`ST_UNION_AGG` is to make a union *vertically*: you have one column of geography objects that you want to aggregate into a single one (perhaps per group..)
At the end of the operation, your rows have been aggregated into only one row (or the number of groups, if you have a `GROUP BY`)